# PHP: Simple HTML DOM Parser - find <p> tag with <table> tag

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am facing web scraping functionality issue.

I have a html file with questions and options.

[image]

My Doubt:

If some questions includes table tag without `<p>` tag like

[image: check my question html file, file.html]

So my code returns only `<p> </p>` tag text only. I need the `<p> </p>` with table `</table>` tag content also.

Please clarify me, how to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: The html in the image is invalid

Comment: please provide images as part of questions with proper formatting. instead of adding images.

Comment: @Haranadh - you mean `please provide "code"`

Comment: Try PHPQuery, or XPath.

Comment: Ideally you want a selector library that can do `p:has(+ table)` (simple html dom can't) otherwise it gets messy.

Answer (score 0):

First you should learn to add your code in the post with in `code` tags which will be easier for use to read and answer. According to your code your code only check for `<p` part and that part has to be at the start of the line if it's not there your code will skip to the next.

To solve this you might have to check the `<td` and then the `<p` use a `if ... else` to differentiate between codes.

Comment: well i guess he just copy pasted the images from a test that he has to succeed in

Comment: Yes seems like it

Answer (score 0):

With simple you would have to do something like this:

```
foreach($html->find('p') as $p){
  if($p->nextSibling() && $p->nextSibling()->tag == 'table'){
    $table = $p->nextSibling();
    echo $p;
    echo $table;
  }
}
```